# Show Only Newsfeed and AboutMe in MySites SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, my-site

Is this possible to display **Newsfeed** and **AboutMe** only in MySites SharePoint 2013 without creating Personal Sites?

I don't want personal sites to be created so i turned OFF "Self-Service Site Creation" for MySites in **Manage Web Applications**. However i can see **AboutMe** and **People** (i can hide People using some CSS) in left navigation on MySites. I wan't Newsfeeds to appear in Left Navigation as well as the actual news feeds to display. Is it possible without creating personal sites?

I have tried disabling the permissions for **All Authenticated Users** in User Profile Service but i think wasn't the correct direction to do this. It only revoked the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a custom branding for our SharePoint 2016.
If you have got a custom branding, you can simply remove the entries for every MySite with the following JS code:

> ```
> $('.static').find('a:contains("Blog")').remove();
> $('.static').find('a:contains("Apps")').remove();
> ```

This JS will run when the "window.location.href" contains **/my**

Another thought is to register a custom action in which you remove the MySite elements, but I didn't try yet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But in that case the Blog and Apps would be still accessible using URL. I wan to disable the functionality.